# Nexus 7 32GB showing 8GB after flash

Tags: nexus-7, stock-android

I had the no command boot loop when trying to enter recovery so I used the nexus root kit to reflash everything which did fix the problem and after a few days of use I noticed that there's only 8GB's available to me now. I presume that this is from the flashing as I had 32 before. To unlock/recognize my memory which part of my nexus will I have to reflash?

Model: Nexus 7 (2012) mobile 32GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to getting the correct size wasn't from the hardware identifying the wrong size, but the partition of the /sdcard/ being the wrong size. I solved this by formatting it with Clockwork. I lost my app data, but most apps remained installed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the same and happened after downgrading from the really slow lollipop to kitkat and rooting again. Formatting or factory reset did not help. 
The solution was to boot into recovery (TWRP) after flashing a ROM and rooting, and there change the file system type. For example I switched from the recognized 8GB ext4 to FAT (this switched the capacity to 32GB) and then back again to ext4. This obviously deletes all apps & data.

Model: Nexus 7 (2012) WiFi, TWRP version 2.8.6.0

Detailed procedure:
On the TWRP home, choose the option "Wipe", then "Advanced Wipe". Now from the available partitions select only Data and tap "Repair or Change File System". The next screen shows the current file system info, where you can tap "Change File System", then choose the desired one and swipe to apply this change. According to my previous instructions you may repeat this procedure twice, once to switch to FAT, then again to ext4.

Comment: Though it should be obvious, a hint for the less experienced: This makes you lose all your installed apps, and also all apps' data.

Comment: Exactly. If performed right after rooting, the apps & data will have already been lost. Otherwise they will be lost during switching file system type, so use with caution.

Comment: "If performed right after rooting, the apps & data will have already been lost." – why that? Since when does rooting destroy data? Or is this specific to the rooting method you've used?

Comment: I was referring to the procedure above: "...after flashing a ROM and rooting".

Comment: Ah – then most likely yes (if that procedure included wiping/factory-reset, as it most often does – though there are exceptions ;) Nevermind, will not start hair-splitting now :)