# Nexus 7 2012 is almost unusable after upgrading to the latest Lollipop. What should I do?

Tags: nexus-7, performance, system-freeze

I have a Nexus 7 2012 wifi. With the latest version of Lollipop it has really become unusable, freezing for a minute or more, or even rebooting while loading a page in Chrome.

I did a system reset, but that did not change much past the few first minutes.

What is the recommended version to have again a usable tablet? Is anyone having a "runbook for dummies" to install Android 4.x (or CM or whatever works fine) ?

Most of the tutorials I found on the Internet are for geeks wishing to experiment. I just want a running system with minimal fuss/risk.

Comment: Found this thead that seems to recommend Android 4.4.4or CM11. I'd love to have some confirmations...

Comment: I second the 4.4.4 downgrade - it was the last version that had no horrible usability challenges with that old Tegra 4 processor, and it's one that I've personally downgraded to on my device.

Comment: What "versions" of Lollipop are you using? I use MultiROM and have  6 different ROMs installed. 2 are Lollipop, 5.0.2 and 5.1. Both run without incidence. Have you tried wiping cache and dalvik-cache from recovery? A better question would be : are you sure your installing the device correct ROM? (There are 2 different 2012's - WiFi only (grouper) and the 3g/WiFi (tilapia)). They will install to each other but will cause corruptions and compatibility issues. I mention this, because Lollipop works really nice on this device.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN I never "tweaked" it.  It got  its 5.1.1 OTA. For me this is a consumer device,  it should just work, without requiring me to spend time studying  what's under the hood. I did wipe the cache, but I have no clue what's the dalvik cache.

Comment: You would have to go into recovery and wipe the dalvik cache there. Most of the time after installing a ROM, even an OTA, the cache and dalvik cache need to be wiped otherwise the issues you been having arise. Do you have a custom recovery installed (CWM or TWRP)? Your accepted answer deals with a custom ROM, which needs a recovery to install.

Comment: I didn't install the SDK to have Wugfresh usable. The program is all inclusive with the exception of the ROM you want installed. It allows for unlocking the boot loader, installing a recovery, side loading apps, fastboot commands, adb commands, and flashing of ROMs; plus a lot more. The Nexus 7 happens to be the easiest device I've ever seen for rooting/ROM'ing. Just have some patience, you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the highly functional nexus root toolkit to do pretty much anything you need to on your Nexus device.

[Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/)

It allows rooting, return to stock, recovery and everything else you would need to repair your nexus 7 2012 WiFi aka 'grouper' / 'nakasi'. You can flash custom  roms with it also.

[image: Nexus Root Toolkit v2.1.0]

Other tools include unlocking or locking the bootloader, adb tools, driver installs. .. you name it, it does it.

[image: Advanced Utilites]

Works with all nexus devices released so far.

[image: Select Nexus device and ROM]

One of the most handy things about it is that it tells you what to do step by step...

[image: Instructions for installing drivers]

Every nexus owner should have this as it's pretty much indispensable.

Comment: I have the same nexus 7 as you, and this tool has been so very useful.

Comment: After trying "lighter" solutions, I ended up re-flashing my Nexus to 4.4.4 with Wugfresh, and I must say that it worked flawlessly. Advice to others: plan for 2+ hours (the first time) and even rebooting your PC. Have some coffee and a good book available :-)

Comment: Also: I had the feeling that Nova launcher makes the tablet a bit more responsive

Comment: Yeah nova launcher is pretty good!  Glad you got it fixed :)

Comment: I  found out that now my 32GB Nexus is displaying 8GB memory. This is evoqued here: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/97169/67779

Comment: Ah I think I had that problem once too, bit of a pain. Solution on that link looks good. Be careful with the EFS partition with android. It's not a big problem with the nexus 7 2012 WiFi version, but for any Android device that uses a mobile connection, this partition contains the IMEI number for the device. Formatting this partition can make your device at worst unusable on a mobile network or at best it will have no valid IMEI number. If possible it is always a good idea to back this partition up before changing any file system.

Comment: The simplest solution is to do a factory reset. That worked for me.

Comment: Now the next problem is preventing the automatic system upgrades...

Comment: edited answer to add screenshots

Answer (score 3):

The official [Google Developers site](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) has the full instructions and image repository on how to install a factory image for any Nexus device, including your "nakasi" Nexus 7 2012. I recommend 4.4.4, but you are free to go back as far as you want until you're comfortable with it's use.

Cyanogenmod also has a [stable 10.2 version](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=grouper&type=stable) (Android 4.3) - you can download the image file here. You can re-use the instructions found on the Google Developers site to install this as well (just target your CM unzip location instead).

BE AWARE: This will wipe your device, and this is all done under your own volition. Flashing a device - regardless of source or instruction - always comes with risk of damaging or rendering the device useless. We are not responsible for it!

Answer (score 3):

Try 'JimTDI's Guide - Tuning the Nexus 7 with Android 5 Lollipop for Maximum Performance!' here https://goo.gl/X0HwAu
The discussion for this post is here https://goo.gl/wqjv76

Comment: very usefull, this helped me understand a few things and helped making the machine more usable. I also installed Nova launcher, which made it faster (my feeling), without spending half a day doing risky things I don't master.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but this is my beloved Nexus 7 3g (2012), "tilapia". Please note that WiFi only version is named "grouper"

First step, install TWRP recovery; the official guides forgot to mention that you have to disable the fastboot lock too, command: `fastboot oem unlock` (and then select Yes on the confirmation screen, on tablet)

Nexus 2012 TWRP installation details [here](https://thegoodcodeinn.blogspot.com/2018/11/install-twrp-on-asus-nexus-7-3g-2012.html)

Then I have installed on my Nexus the Android AOSP (vanilla 7.1.2. andorid) with tilapia/grouper support released by AndDiSa on XDA forums.
Main thread is [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7/development/rom-android-7-aosp-grouper-t3467514).

Now it works really fast, I can use the web browser, play and see movies with no hiccups.

I quote my "success story" form XDA forum:

> I have successfully installed the
>   `aosp_tilapia-7.1.2-ota-eng-20181112.ds.zip` on my Asus Nexus 3g 2012
>   (tilapia), I also installed `open_gapps-arm-7.1-pico` and `Magisk v17.3`.
>   I installed your Android release, by using TWRP-3.2.3-0-tilapia, over
>   the Asus original fully updated Lollipop. In fact the most tricky part
>   was installing TWRP
>
> During installation the initial OS configuration failed, multiple
>   times (I tried with reboots), just during the user account selection.
>   Using the suggested `SetupWizardFixCrDroidNexus7.zip` fix, fixed the
>   problem, and I was able to complete the device configuration.
>
> Finally: My Nexus is back to life, is very responsive, browsing and
>   playing movies are very fast... I have not tried all the functions
>   (not tried camera yet).
>
> With official Lollipop my Nexus was simply unusable, u-n-u-s-a-b-l-e,
>   I used to think that my beloved Nexus was simply too old for the new
>   applications. I think now that Asus(or Google, is a Nexus) released
>   defective OS versions for manufacturer-planned-obsolescence

Comment: Interesting. I still have that tablet (unused). I might give your solution a try. Is it feasible for a non specialist ?

Comment: It depends, there are passages (TWRP installation) for sure where technical experience helps to not get stucked. i.e., you need fastboot and adb commands,  -> so you have to install Android-SDK -> to invoke its adb/fastboot commands perhaps you have to  invoke them from command prompt from the right path, I have no Windows OS but Linux, you must certainly try and try again, more times. And for sure you need 1)Patience 2)Method. I think that with no mistakes an expert guy needs about an hour to make the job done. But I cannot say exactly what the minimum level is.. I'm sorry.

Comment: Added my TWRP guide link, https://thegoodcodeinn.blogspot.com/2018/11/install-twrp-on-asus-nexus-7-3g-2012.html

Comment: I try: I think that an average programmer can make the job done.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to improve performance on My Nexus 7 2012 (Nakasi) was to Unlock Bootloader then flashed TWRP v3.3.0, then flashed Lineage OS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2 Nougat) via TWRP,  Recommended GAPPS are "opengapps pico" (arm) and to root it I flashed Magisk v18 and now it took life. Performance improve like 90% now is pretty much usable. (it's April 16 2019) so belive me when I say it is usable and performance wise is awesome.

Comment: interesting, thanks. Could you eventually the necessary links ? Thx !

Answer (score 1):

I recently got my Nexus 7 2012 usable and fast after 2 years resting in a drawer with rooted Lollipop using suggestions from [this site](http://www.tonisoto.com/2015/02/nexus-7-como-solucionar-la-lentitud-al-instalar-lollipop/) (in Spanish) like disable all gestures at Language Input/Gboard and disable graphic animations in Developer mode.

Comment: Looks interesting, thx. I'll give it a try